# How to update State of chart.js in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mean, mern

I am passing data from **parent** to **child component  in react** , **from App.js to chart.js** through **props** and the values are passsed and i can see them **logged the the console in child** component but i want to  **change the state of chart data property as the props values changed** so that the graph also gets changed .

here is my code for child **component/chart.js** file

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Line ,Bar} from "react-chartjs-2"

const Bargraph = ({totalIncome,Balance,Expenses}) => {

**console.log("data is ",totalIncome,Balance,Expenses)**

const [state,setState] = useState({

    labels:["Total Income","Expenses","Current Balance"],
    datasets:[{

        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data:[totalIncome,Balance,Expenses]

    }]
})



    return ( 
<section className="chart mb-4 mt-lg-5">

<div className="container-lg">
    <div className="text-center">

        <h2>  Income , Expenses and Current Balance  </h2>
        <p className="lead"> Bar graph showing Total icnome , Expenses and remaining balance </p>
    
    </div>

<div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3 g-4">

<div className="col-md-5">

<Line data={state}
    
    options={{
            title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Income , Expenses and Current Balance',
              fontSize:20
            },
            legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'right'
            }
          }}

 />




</div>


<div className="col-md-5">

<Bar data={state}
    
    options={{
            title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Income , Expenses and Current Balance',
              fontSize:20
            },
            legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'right'
            }
          }}

 />



</div>
</div>




</div>

</section>

     );
}
 
export default Bargraph;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use useEffect to get updated values.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Line ,Bar} from "react-chartjs-2"

var Bargraph = ({totalIncome,Balance,Expenses}) => {

**console.log("data is ",totalIncome,Balance,Expenses)**

const [state,setState] = useState({

    labels:["Total Income","Expenses","Current Balance"],
    datasets:[{

        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data:[totalIncome,Balance,Expenses]

    }]
})

useEffect(() => {
    setState({
        labels:["Total Income","Expenses","Current Balance"],
        datasets:[{
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
            borderWidth: 2,
            data:[totalIncome,Balance,Expenses]
    
        }]
    })

}, [totalIncome,Balance,Expenses]);


    return ( 
<section className="chart mb-4 mt-lg-5">

<div className="container-lg">
    <div className="text-center">

        <h2>  Income , Expenses and Current Balance  </h2>
        <p className="lead"> Bar graph showing Total icnome , Expenses and remaining balance </p>
    
    </div>

<div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3 g-4">

<div className="col-md-5">

<Line data={state}
    
    options={{
            title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Income , Expenses and Current Balance',
              fontSize:20
            },
            legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'right'
            }
          }}

 />




</div>


<div className="col-md-5">

<Bar data={state}
    
    options={{
            title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Income , Expenses and Current Balance',
              fontSize:20
            },
            legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'right'
            }
          }}

 />



</div>
</div>




</div>

</section>

     );
}
 
export default Bargraph;
```

Answer (score 4):

The other answers about useEffect show how you can achieve this when using state. Your example, however, does not require state at all. Think about props as very similar to state:
Changes trigger a rerender automatically so if you can calculate something directly from them, do it in the render function/functional component.

```
import { Line ,Bar} from "react-chartjs-2"

const Bargraph = ({totalIncome,Balance,Expenses}) => {

// simply calculate the chartData from the props
const chartData = {

    labels:["Total Income","Expenses","Current Balance"],
    datasets:[{

        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75,192,192,1)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,1)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data:[totalIncome,Balance,Expenses]

    }]
}



    return ( 
<section className="chart mb-4 mt-lg-5">

<div className="container-lg">
    <div className="text-center">

        <h2>  Income , Expenses and Current Balance  </h2>
        <p className="lead"> Bar graph showing Total icnome , Expenses and remaining balance </p>
    
    </div>

<div className="row justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3 g-4">

<div className="col-md-5">

<Line data={chartData}
    
    options={{
            title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Income , Expenses and Current Balance',
              fontSize:20
            },
            legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'right'
            }
          }}

 />




</div>


<div className="col-md-5">

<Bar data={chartData}
    
    options={{
            title:{
              display:true,
              text:'Income , Expenses and Current Balance',
              fontSize:20
            },
            legend:{
              display:true,
              position:'right'
            }
          }}

 />



</div>
</div>




</div>

</section>

     );
}
 
export default Bargraph;
```

Comment: thanks bro that was really helpful and important point you addded thanks again!!:)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useEffect` to update your state when props change

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setState([
      {
        backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
        borderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [totalIncome, Balance, Expenses],
      },
    ]);
  }, [totalIncome, Balance, Expenses]);
```

Comment: Thank a lot for you time and help :)